# How to assign prvReadActivity to a prinicipal team

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, security-roles

We are trying to create a web application that can create Service Activity entities in CRM Online. The web application stalls out with the error "Principal team (Id=fee1cfb8-9e6e-e511-80e7-3863bb36ebd8, type=9) is missing prvReadActivity privilege (Id=650c14fe-3521-45fe-a000-84138688e45d)."

I have located the Security Roles area of CRM Online but I am unable to determine WHICH of the roles corresponds to prvReadActivity, and for which entity.

Does anyone know how to apply prvReadActivity privilege to a team?

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`prvReadActivity` is a privileges for read of the activity entities. [Check out Security role UI to privilege mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547441.aspx) for a mapping.

A single security role can contain many privileges. If you open a security role on the core tab, at the top there should be a row for activity. So give your team a security role which contains access to the activity entity, try testing with system administrator to be sure as that has access to everything.